# Will the Windows 10 install expire?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have registered to get the free download for Windows 10 when it comes out. However, I have heard that certain functions will not be available for Windows 10 when it is initially released (such as the ability to play DVD's).

So once I have the OS downloaded to my computer, will I be able to install it whenever I want? Will the downloaded material expire after a year or any set period of time or can I keep it forever?

Comment: Where did you read that you'll get a code? Reserving the OS only means you'll get the bits over time till you're ready to upgrade on July 29 (or later). Also, Win10 will include a free DVD playback app for Media Center users.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I meant to say install. I'm a little scatter-brained right now so I got that confused with something else.

Oh, okay. Will Windows 7 programs be compatible with Windows 10, though?

Comment: When you use the Get Windows 10 app to reserve your download, it will check your system for hardware and software compatibility automatically. You can view the report at any time.

Comment: But will my third party programs work? (Stuff such as Paint.NET, GIMP, etc.) Or will I have to wait for them to separately release a Windows 10 version to run them without compatibility mode?

Comment: Did you read my previous comment? It will look through your programs and try and identify (at least for the well-known ones) whether there are any potential problems that might block the upgrade. As for compatibility in general, there's no reason your programs will stop working on Win10. MS is generally very careful about maintaining backwards compatibility. I did not need to run Paint.NET, GIMP etc. in compatibility mode even when Win7 and 8 were brand new.

Comment: Windows 10 will be able to run any program Windows 7 supports and all universal application on the windows store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll not expire after a year once you've activated it. Only a fresh installation activated after July 29, 2016 will need to be paid for by Windows 7 and 8 users.

It is unclear at this time how situations like a clean install will be handled, both during the first year and later.

Comment: I bet they extend the expiry date.

Comment: @Moab: Maybe they will. Even if they don't I'm more concerned about how clean installs will work. If the installer accepts Win7/8 keys directly that'll be the best surprise ever.

Comment: One can dream is suppose. I doubt they will allow that, but who knows, they are desperate for users to move to W10 asap.

Comment: @Moab: They have to provide some way at least for people to perform clean installs, as well as to reinstall already activated copies of Win10 after year 1. People cannot be expected to reinstall their old OS and then upgrade again every time they need to start from scratch (especially when Reset doesn't work for some reason).

Comment: Actually they don't and have done this in previous versions of Windows. I don't think they will but is all speculation until they release the final; version and all documentation.

Answer (score 2):

No, your licence will not expire.

In simple words, you are getting the complete version of *Windows 10*, and you can keep it for ever, for that device.

When someone says that all features won't work they are trying to say that your computer hardware does not support all features. For example, if you don't have a touch screen monitor, you can't use the touch facility.

And with not being able to play DVDs, it means, [Microsoft has discontinued Media Center](http://www.zdnet.com/article/rip-windows-media-center/). But don't worry, Windows 10 comes with an even better app for this purpose.

Don't believe me? Check out the official [Win10 FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-faq?ocid=win10_auxapp_LearnMore_win10faq). Every thing I have said is said there as well.

Hope this helps =)